# How can I install an early Java 8 release on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I'm using OS X version 10.8.5 and I'm trying to install the Java 8 early access JDK from this link:

https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

After double click-ing the icon from the dmg file how do I point to that JDK from an IDE?

Thanks

Comment: See setting in the IDE. There must be an option to configure JDK.

Comment: This depends very much on which IDE you are using. So which is it?

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't find where was installed the JDk. I found that it is in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk

And Eclipse doesn't let me use Java 8 syntax (I'm using the lastest Kepler) but I can compile from the terminal which is fine.

Comment: Is is possible to use the Java 8 syntax. Check out "Early Access Binaries" section at http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8